# jQuery Validator Credit Card Number + Type Match

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Trying to add a customer jQuery validator method that basically checks the card type and the credit card number for validity.

ie. If the type is MasterCard, if the card number doesn't start with 5, it's invalid or if the type is Visa, if the card number doesn't start with 4, it's invalid. My company only charges MC or Visa, so no others are needed.

```
$.validator.addMethod("CCNumber", function(value, element, param) {
  if (param == "MasterCard") {
    return value.substring(0,1) != 5;   
  }
  else if (param == "Visa") {
    return value.substring(0,1) != 4;   
  }
});
```

Calling it here:

```
cardnumber: {
  required: true,
  creditcard: true,
  minlength: 13,
  maxlength: 16,
  digits: true,
  CCNumber: function(){ return $('#cardtype').val(); }
},
```

And the message...

```
cardnumber: {
  required: "Please enter a valid credit card number",
  minlength: "Please enter a valid credit card number",
  maxlength: "Please enter a valid credit card number",
  digits: "Your credit card number cannot contain spaces.",
  CCNumber: "WRONG"
},
```

Finally, the HTML:

```
<select name="cardtype" id="cardtype">
  <option value="MasterCard">MasterCard</option>
  <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
</select>
```

I've never written a jQuery method before, but nothing is happening here. I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong, as I've tried to look at other methods, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why are you asking for the type at all?

Comment: @FergusMorrow: Yes.  The OP should just get rid of it.

Comment: What is `sub` supposed to do? Did you mean `substring`?

Comment: Was about to ask the same question.

Comment: Wow that's weird. It is a ["non-standard" function that wraps stuff in `<sub>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sub). Was wondering why I wasn't getting an error using it.

Comment: Updated the OP with changes I found. Closer to the right track I think.

Comment: If you're really using the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), as your question is tagged, then why not simply use the built-in method for CC validation included in the ["additional methods" file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.js)?

Comment: Think I fixed it. Setting return value.substring(0,1) == 5; instead of not equals. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) already has additional methods available for things like this.

The following is the default method used in the ["Additional Methods" file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/additional-methods.js), but then edited down for only Visa & Mastercard.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("creditcardtypes", function(value, element, param) {
    if (/[^0-9-]+/.test(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

    var validTypes = 0x0000;

    if (param.mastercard)
        validTypes |= 0x0001;
    if (param.visa)
        validTypes |= 0x0002;

    if (validTypes & 0x0001 && /^(5[12345])/.test(value)) { //mastercard
        return value.length == 16;
    }
    if (validTypes & 0x0002 && /^(4)/.test(value)) { //visa
        return value.length == 16;
    }
    return false;
}, "Please enter a valid credit card number.");
```

Comment: Can you show an example of using the creditcardtypes method as part of validate rules?

Comment: @dirt, the parameter you pass into this method is `visa` or `mastercard` based on a select list, and then the input field is validated only for that card type.  That's the idea anyway.

Comment: @ViralPatel - you can’t - php has nothing to do with any of this.  This is jQuery, which is client side code.  Please do not ask new questions in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function acountNo(e) {
  var value = $(e).val()
  var count = value.length;

  if (count == 4 || count == 9 || count == 14) {
    value = value + " ";
    $(e).val(value);
  } else if (count == 20) {
    $(e).val('');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="account_number" oninput="acountNo(this)" class="form-control acountNo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Card Number ...">
```

Comment: The code works, but explaining to viewers what it's accomplishing would be beneficial.

Answer (score -2):

sub() is not a javascript function. The function you're looking for is substring(). Even easier, though, would be charAt(0), since you only want the first character.